# A is a matrix of positive defined quadratic form. How can I show, $A^{-1}$ is the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Let a square matrix A is a matrix of positive defined quadratic form. How can I show, that $A^{-1}$ also a matrix of a positive defined quadratic form?

Positive defined quadratic form is
A(x,y), that all it's corner minors are positive.

Inverse matrix is a matrix, contains all minors of the source matrix.

It must be linked somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is positive-definite, then $x^TAx >0$ for all $x$.

Since $A$ is invertible then for any $y$ we can find some $x$ such that $Ax=y$, but we have:

$Ax = y \implies x^TAx=x^Ty$

$x=A^{-1}y \implies y^TA^{-1}y=y^Tx$

$x^Ty$ is a real number, therefore $x^Ty=(x^Ty)^T=y^Tx$. This implies that:

$y^TA^{-1}y = x^TAx> 0$

Since $y$ was arbitrary, this proves that $A^{-1}$ is positive definite.

Comment: If it is positive definite, then you actually get $x^T A x  > 0$, what you have is semi-positive definite.

Comment: @math.n00b why $x^T Ax >0$ Ax>0, but x can be < 0

Comment: @so-olitary: $Ax$ is a vector, so it's meaningless to say $Ax>0$. The definition of a positive definite matrix says that $x^TAx$ must be positive for any $x$. Check wikipedia for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Comment: Oh, it is a late night. $ X^T A X $ is a definition of positive definite quadratic form. Thank everybody for your answers.

Comment: @so-olitary: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As $A \in S_{++}(\mathbb{R})$, then we have $x^T A x > 0$. Now recall the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are precisely the reciprocals of $A$, and therefore $A^{-1}$ is also positive definite. In fact we get non-singularity as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=Ax$. $A$ is positive definite and hence also invertible. Thus, it follows that $
x=A^{-1}z.
$
Premultiply by $z'$ to get $z'x=z'A^{-1}z$. But, $z'=x'A'$ so what you have is actually
$$
x'A'x=z'A^{-1}z>0
$$
since $A=A'$ and $x'A'x>0$ by the nature of semi definite matrices.